# Mudar a fonte de section

Tags: latex

Tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
\section{Referencial teórico}
```

Quero alterar a fonte para 14pt como fazer sem alterar o restante do texto que se encontra com fonte 12pt

Comment: Não vás por aí! em LaTeX a vantagem é não pensar em tamanhos nem fontes -- só em conceitos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem a opção de pelo menos dois pacotes para mudar a fonte das seções e subseções.

**Pacote [`sectsty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

% Para definir a fonte da seção
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test \newline
\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont test \newline
\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont test

\end{document}
```

**Pacote [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Para definir a fonte da seção
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test \newline
\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont test \newline
\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont test


\end{document}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103290

Para mais detalhes dependendo da `classe` do documento: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59727